# SymbolicC`CSwitch basically broken?

Tags: symbolic, code-generation

The CSwitch manual page gives the example

```
CSwitch["val", 1, CAssign["i", 10], CBreak[], 2, CAssign["i", 3], 
  CBreak[]] // ToCCodeString
```

which generates this **illegitimate** C code:

```
switch ( val)
{
case 1:
i = 10;

case break;:
2;

case i = 3:
break;
}
```

And I cannot even get it to produce just the first case, i.e.

```
switch ( val)
{
case 1:
i = 10;
break;
}
```

I tried removing the rest from the first example,

```
CSwitch["val", 1, CAssign["i", 10], CBreak[]] // ToCCodeString
```

but this gives

`ToCCodeString::unk: An unknown element, CSwitch[val,1,CAssign[i,10],CBreak[]], was found when generating code >>`

`CUnknownElement[CSwitch[val, 1, CAssign[i, 10], CBreak[]]]`

and

`CSwitch["val", 1, {CAssign["i", 10], CBreak[]}] // ToCCodeString`

generates the right code but again gives a message.

Also, the syntax-highlighting for CSwitch should probably tolerate any amount of arguments.

Is there something wrong with my setup or can somebody confirm this?

This is 10.4.

Comment: `CSwitch` is a little bent, but it's documentation shows serious fractures.

Comment: Was this reported? I still see it in the very latest version. Shouldn't we add the bugs tag?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `CSwitch` looks like it was written by somebody who didn't understand what the `SymbolicC` package or, for that matter, what a C switch is supposed to do. The following produces something more like C code and makes more sense as Mathematica code.

```
Needs["SymbolicC`"]
CSwitch["val",
  1, {CAssign["i", 10], CBreak[]},
  2, {CAssign["i", 3], CBreak[]}] // ToCCodeString
```

[image: ccode]

Still I would say that the `SymbolicC` package is very much a work in progress.

Comment: Is it an officially supported package, i.e. would you contact support about this?

Comment: @masterxilo. Yes, it is an officially provided package and should be supported by Wolfram Research, Inc. I encourage you to contact WRI tech support concerning what you have found.

Comment: @masterxilo Yes, report it. Similar bugs I reported in this package in the past were fixed.